# Login using facebook api

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have code like below. Why `$userId` is always `0`? When I click Login button I get `B.login() called when user is already connected.`. When I check allowed apps in fb, this app is added. It looks like I'm connected so it should be my `id` instead of `0`.

```
<pre>
define('YOUR_APP_ID', ###);

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => ###,
  'secret' => '###',
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();
echo $userId;
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <?php if ($userId) { 
      $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId); ?>
      Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '<? echo('####'); ?>',
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          oauth      : true,
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };

      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue when i used **FBJS SDK** for connect also i worried about myself how this functionality run and how this issue solved but seriously not success...

I refer you this link  https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk because its easy to use  for facebook connect....

Also i don't want to copy my code here because its too much lengthy and belong to codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in IE? If so, you need to get the P3P header to all your page.

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

If not, give the good rights to the user when you login into the application.